# M2 equivalent of trying to process some information and return html in an AJAX response

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

What's best practice for an ajax request which involves - receiving some params in a request, loading data based on these params, processing this data, generating html and sending the html back in a json response?

For instance, say I have a product id that I pass as a param, I have to
return html for related product listing html as a json response.

In M1 I would create a controller action and do the following:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
$this->loadLayout();
$html = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('mycustom_module/block')- >setProduct($product)->toHtml();
$response('html' => $html);
$this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content Type: json');
$this->sendResponse();
return $this;
```

In my custom module's block class I would basically load the collection of related products for the product and form the html in the template and return the html output in the json. How do I go about doing this sort of a thing with M2?

Doing a similar thing as M1 while making sure I use best practices like using DI instead of object manager is good enough? Or would you design this sort of functionality differently?

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly in your controller will have code below. I have not test yet but i will work.
Class will extends `Magento\Backend\App\Action`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Encoder $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder $jsonDecoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $rawResultFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    \YourNamespace\Module\Model\EntityFactory $entityFactory
){
    $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
    $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    $this->rawResultFactory = $rawResultFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Main function `execute`

```
/**
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    //Get json data from ajax POST
    $requestData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param');
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
    $result = ['success' => false];

    if ($requestData) {
        try {

            //decode data
            $menuData = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($requestData)
            //Do something : load model, collection here
            $products = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $this->_session->getStore()->getId());  

            $products->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
            $products->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

            $products->load();
            $result['success'] =  true;         

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    //Force header encode data to json
    $response = $this->rawResultFactory->create()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return $response->setContents($this->jsonEncoder->encode($result));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

-- `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory` to create the block.
-- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory` to return Json format.
-- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` to get product

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
  */
protected $layoutFactory;


/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
 */
protected $resultRawFactory;

/**
  * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $product

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    .....
) {

      $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory; 
      $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
      $this->product = $product;
      parent::__construct($context);

}

public function execute() {

$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');

$product = $this->product->getById($productId);

$layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();

$block = $layout->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Custom')
                ->setData('product', $product)
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::custom.phtml')
                ->toHtml();

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */

$resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
$resultRaw->setContents($block);

//$this->getResponse()->setBody($block); <= We also can use setBody.

return $resultRaw;

}
```